# CHtml:submitButton and zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton doesn't work well when the text has special characters

Tags: php, yii

Yii Framework: I try to add a spanish text for these buttons and, as result, the button doesn't show any caption (without text).

However, if I write caption text without special characters (e.g. ñ, á, é, etc.), it works well.

Any ideas?

My code is the following:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton',
         array('name'=>'submit',
               'caption'=>'Contraseña',
               'htmlOptions'=> array('style'=>'background:#52A7E7;color:#ffffff;'),
              ));
```

For CHtml:submitButton is the same problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Replace the ñ by `&#328;` (Numerical Code) see for other characters http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm
- Add **'encode'=>false** to your htmlOptions array

See Example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton', 
     array(
        'name'=>'submit', 
        'caption'=>'Contrase&#328;a',
        'htmlOptions'=> array(
             'style'=>'background:#52A7E7;color:#ffffff;',
             'encode'=>false
         ), 
     );
```

Comment: Thank you! your solution has fixed the problem. Moreover, I tested it using 'friendly code' (e.g. ntilde;) and it works too. The trick is 'encode'=> false.